# Resetting loop when going to next page

Tags: python, selenium, loops

I have the following code, that downloads files:

```
followLoop = range(1, 49)
for x in followLoop:

    try:

        xpath = '//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGridFacturen_ctl00__'
        xpath += str(x)
        xpath += '"]/td[10]/input'

        time.sleep(2)

        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()

    except NoSuchElementException:
            print('exception')
            nextPage = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGridFacturen_ctl00"]/tfoot/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div[3]/input[1]')
            nextPage.click()
            continue
```

When it throws an exception, I want the loop range to reset on the next page. So when page 1 throws an exception, I want in to start on page 2 with 1.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: please give more details about your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a while loop like this.

```
count = 1
while count < 49:
   try:
        xpath = '//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGridFacturen_ctl00__' + str(x) + '"]/td[10]/input'
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()

        
   except NoSuchElementException:
        print('exception')
        nextPage = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGridFacturen_ctl00"]/tfoot/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div[3]/input[1]')
        nextPage.click()
        count = 1
```

This will work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need another counter you are using the same counter for multiple pages. For example if you don’t find item 9 on page 1 you go to page 2 then look for item 10

```py
pages  = range(1, 49). # change to how many pages you want to look at

for page in pages:
    
    for item in range(1, 49):

        try:
    
            xpath = f'//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGridFacturen_ctl00__{item}"]/td[10]/input'
    
            time.sleep(2)
    
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
    
        except NoSuchElementException:
                print('exception')
                nextPage = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGridFacturen_ctl00"]/tfoot/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div[3]/input[1]')
                nextPage.click()
                break
```